# Track Events with Prometheus Counters

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

Using Prometheus for things that are per second works really great and I've had great success with `rate` and `irate`. I am just at a loss how to graph something that's happening very rarely and is a big deal.

So I have a counter I am incrementing that's called `job_failed`. Whenever that happens it shows up in my instant-vector. If I graph it directly it always goes up and I see a bump in the graph, but this isn't giving me clear enough indication that a job has failed. So I'd like to have it be a spike in a zeroed graph.

If I do a `rate(job_failed[15s])` I get my spike - but it's a per second spike so it's value is 0.1 although the change I want is 1.
I tried `increase(job_failed[1m])` but that is also not adding up correctly, occasionally leaving me with values like 2.18 etc.

Is there a way to only see a single spike? This seems like a rather trivial thing but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus is suited more to high volume than low volume events, as at low volumes artifacts from how we keep things accurate on average show up.

So for example `rate(job_failed[15s])` with an increase of 1 over the 15 seconds is 1/15 = 0.066/s. Rounding could make that show as 0.1.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=67Ulrq6DxwA goes into more detail as to how this all works.

The short version is what you're doing now is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've gotten, for errors by server, is:

sum by (hostname) (increase(job_failed_count{app_name="foo"}[1m]))

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `increase` instead of `rate`.

Comment: Increase is just doing `rate() * 60` so the numbers look a lot better but as brian-brazil (one of the core prometheus ppl) mentioned above the way prometheus calculates / stores data it's not really useful for counting low-volume stuff..

Answer (score -1):

For similar requirement, I was using delta function with threshold configured as per requirement.

https://prometheus.io/docs/querying/functions/#delta

Comment: Delta is for use with gauges, not counters. I'd generally avoid that function, as usually you actually want deriv any time delta comes up.

Comment: Agreed on data type to use it for, but it makes a great tool for anomaly detection.